# ubuntu 16 install gstreamer but gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc file is not found anywhere

Tags: plugins, gstreamer, apt-get, pocketsphinx

(Using ubuntu 16 0n my mac pro.)

> To integrate gstreamer and pocketsphinx, I need three .pc files as the offical website says:
>
> - gstreamer-1.0.pc
> - gstreamer-base-1.0.pc
> - gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc

I start a new empty ubuntu 18.
install the gstreamer through

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev
```

But only two of the three important .pc files exist after the previous command.
If I cd to **/usr/** and run :

```
sudo find . -print | grep -i 'gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0'
```

the terminal returns empty( not found).
At the same time,
`sudo find . -print | grep -i 'gstreamer-base-1.0'`

and

```
sudo find . -print | grep -i 'gstreamer-1.0'
```

will give me correct paths.

Where is the missing **gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc** file? Thank you.

If there are only two but not three of the .pc files, the configuration of pocketsphinx will not work.

Comment: **sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev ** helped me generate the missing  gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`**sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev**`

helped me generate the missing gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc file. 
Those two are needed.