# How can I tell if wx.media.MediaCtrl was included in my installation of wxPython?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, wxpython, wxwidgets

**What's the problem:** I am trying to get wxPython, specifically wx.media.MediaCtrl, working on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian bullseye. I'm trying to play an mp4 video when a button is pushed and I keep getting errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[User Name]/Downloads/testapp/testapp.py", line 152, in lesson_one_frame
    frame = videoFrame(title=title)
  File "/home/[User Name]/Downloads/testapp/testapp.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER)
NotImplementedError
```

Here is some more information on the versions of things I am running:

- wxPython: 4.2.0
- GStreamer Core Library: 1.18.4
- Python: 3.9.2
- pip: 22.3.1

**What I've Tried:** After googling the initial issue I found this StackOverFlow issue [Getting a "NotImplementedError" in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14302005/10963018) where the top answer says this:

> The wxMediaCtrl is an optional part of the build, and it will automatically be excluded if wxWidgets' configure script was not able to finde the right dependent libraries or their -devel packages are not installed. When wxPython is built using a wxWigets without wxMediaCtrl then it creates a stub class that simply raises NotImplementedError if you try to use it.

I was unsure if my issue was a problem with wx.media.MediaCtrl not being part of the build or Gstreamer not working so I tested GStreamer. I typed this `gst-launch-1.0 videotextsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` into a terminal and it worked to show the test video.

After testing GStreamer I started looking for ways to tell if wxMediaCtrl was part of the build and I found this StackOverFlow issue [wxMediaCtrl excluded during the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57886608/10963018) which the answer suggested some library dependency might be missing and to try the steps listed here https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/. I have followed all of these steps and it still gives me the `NotImplementedError`.

**Code Sample:**

Here is my code sample for using wxMediaCtrl

```py
import wx, wx.media
import wx.html


class videoFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        
        # This line is where the problem is.
        self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER)
        self.media = 'testVideo.mp4'

        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.quit)
        if self.testMedia.Load(self.media):
            pass
        else:
            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)
    
    def play(self, event):
        self.testMedia.Play()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()


class mainAppFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        lessonOneBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Lesson 1")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLessonOnePress, lessonOneBtn)
        

    def OnLessonOnePress(self, event):
        title = 'Lesson One'
        frame = videoFrame(title=title)
```

**EDIT****: After posting I checked my build.log file to see if I missed anything and I found this:

```
checking for GST... configure: GStreamer 1.7.2+ not available. Not using GstPlayer and falling back to 1.0
checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 1.0 not available, falling back to 0.10
checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 0.10 not available
configure: WARNING: GStreamer not available... disabling wxMediaCtrl
```

So it seems that when I was installing wxPython for some reason it could not find GStreamer. I believe GStreamer is installed correctly because the command `gst-launch-1.0 videotextsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` worked.

Here are the packages I have downloaded related to GStreamer:

- libgstreamer1.0-dev
- libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
- libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev
- libgstreamer1.0-0
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
- gstreamer1.0-libav
- gstreamer1.0-doc
- gstreamer1.0-tools
- gstreamer1.0-x
- gstreamer1.0-alsa
- gstreamer1.0-gl
- gstreamer1.0-gtk3

All of these seem to be located in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/. I have also tried to add them to my pkg-config by using `pkg-config pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` like it says to do here https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c but I get the error:

```
Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'gstreamer-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found
```

I then tried to use `locate gstreamer | grep pc` and there are no .pc files for GStreamer even though it is installed. I'll update if I can figure out any more information.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490082/ubuntu-16-install-gstreamer-but-gstreamer-plugins-base-1-0-pc-file-is-not-found

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thank you for the link, but that did not work to generate .pc files for gstreamer.

Comment: Installation on a Raspberry Pi looks a little clunky see here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=109268

Answer (score 0):

The [libstreamer1.0-dev package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libgstreamer1.0-dev) should contain the `gstreamer-1.0.pc` file, so it's really strange that you say that you don't have it even though you've installed the package.

If you do have the file, you may try setting `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` to the directory containing it explicitly to help configure find it, but normally it shouldn't be necessary. Please check your `config.log`, maybe you can find some reason for the failure to find it there.